# How can I check the first Login with Facebook in swift?

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift3

I want to check the first login with Facebook so I can give 2 options:
1. if it is the first login to send the into authentification step 2 where they need to add extra details.
2. option 2, if the user logged in with Facebook already to be sent into homepage.

I am using firebase, I know how to keep them logged but this part I can not figure it out. I am using this function that works properly, it is just the part with sending them to the right viewController that gives me trouble:

```
func loginWithFacebookAction() {
    print("Login with Facebook clicked")

    FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], from: self) { (result, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print("FB login failed", err as Any)
        } else if (result?.isCancelled)! {
            print("The user cancelled loggin in")
            self.segueProgramaticWithPresent(viewController: LoginController())
        } else {

            if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil) {
                print("Go to main page")
                self.facebookRequestUserDetails()
                self.segueToAnotherView(storyboard: "Main", identifier: "SWRevealViewController")
            } else {
                print("Go to Step 2 - add more details")
                self.segueProgramaticWithPresent(viewController: CreateAccountST2())
            }

        }
```

I am using the FacebokToken to check, but as the user clicks the button it will always return true.

Answer (score 0):

1. Store the registered facebook users with their `facebook_id` on a
   server side database.
2. Then, when a user logged in successfully with facebook, you will get
   the access_token with `FBSDKAccessToken.current()` and send it to
   your server side api,
3. On server side request to the graph api with that `access_token` and
   get the `facebookuser_id`

   https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={accesstoken}  which
   returns simply a json which contains `id` field.
4. When you get the `facebookuser_id` then you are able to check if user
   has already exist on your database.
5. If doesn't exist, create a new user and response with a code which
   says "hey this is a new user so you should get extra details from
   her/him"
6. If already exist return the user.